# Mist with Photo in compositing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a problem with Mist.
I am compositing a photo with blender, using the cool mist tool.
The problem is I don't have any clue how to exclude the foliage over my cosplayer model.
[image: over my model]

This is my cycles node so far. I suppose I need to add another mix node, but I didn't succeed without excluding the entire photo.
[image: cycles]

Comment: You could use the Alpha Over node for combining it and using the mask to exclude anything in the area of the character.

Comment: @rjg that's what I was thinking, but I don't know where to put the alpha over or the combination to achieve this

Comment: I'd say alpha over last (before the color grading), if the character isn't supposed to be affected by the mist.

Comment: @rjg the thing is the mist should affect the character, but you can see too the foliage is transparent in the body of the model